# Displaying Meta Box Image

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta, single

I have some problems displaying info from my custom meta box in my custom post type single. I'm using [Reusable Custom Wordpress Meta Boxes](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes) by Tammy Hart.

I'm able to display the textfields using this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'hjemmeside', true); ?>
```

But I can't get the image to display, instead DEBUG is telling me that it is an "Undefined variable: post_meta_data in". Currently I'm using this script:

```
<?php
    $custom_image = $post_meta_data['image'][0];
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($custom_image, 'thumbnail');
?>
```

Is this wrong? ID for the image meta field is "image".

This is my functions.php file (Only the meta box part):

```
include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/metaboxes/meta_box.php');

$prefix = 'sample_';

$fields = array(
array( // Hjemmeside
    'label' => 'Hjemmeside', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Skriv inn hjemmesiden til butikken her.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'hjemmeside', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'text' // type of field
),
array( // Facebook
    'label' => 'Facebook', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Skriv inn facebookadressen til butikken her.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'facebook', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'text' // type of field
),
array( // Telefon
    'label' => 'Telefon', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Skriv inn telefonnummeret til butikken her.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'telefon', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'text' // type of field
),
array( // Mailadresse
    'label' => 'Mailadresse', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Skriv inn mailadressen til butikken her.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'mailadresse', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'text' // type of field
),
array( // Senterbeliggenhet
    'label' => 'Senterbeliggenhet', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Skriv inn hvor butikken er plassert i senteret.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'senterbeliggenhet', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'textarea' // type of field
),
array( // Logo
    'label' => 'Logo', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'Last opp logoen til butikken her.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'image', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'image' // type of field
),
);

/**
 * Instantiate the class with all variables to create a meta box
 * var $id string meta box id
 * var $title string title
 * var $fields array fields
 * var $page string|array post type to add meta box to
 * var $js bool including javascript or not
 */
$sample_box = new custom_add_meta_box( 'sample_box', 'Butikkinformasjon', $fields, 'butikker', true );
```

Also, [here's the link to the meta_box.php file](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/metaboxes/meta_box.php), which holds all the codes relevant to the meta boxes :)

Here's the output of `var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID));`

```
array(11) { 
  ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
  } 
  ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(12) "1363962761:1" 
  } 
  ["_thumbnail_id"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(2) "58" 
  } 
  ["sample_text"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(11) "99 88 99 88" 
  } 
  ["sample_image"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "0" 
  } 
  ["sample_hjemmeside"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(21) "www.ethic-clinique.no" 
  } 
  ["sample_facebook"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(31) "www.facebook.com/ethic-clinique" 
  } 
  ["sample_telefon"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(11) "99 88 99 88" 
  } 
  ["sample_mailadresse"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(22) "post@ethic-clinique.no" 
  } 
  ["sample_senterbeliggenhet"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(42) "Tredje butikken til høyre i andre etasje." 
  } 
  ["sample_logo"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(42) "Tredje butikken til høyre i andre etasje." 
  } 
}
```

New var_dump:

```
array(12) { 

        ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } 
        ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1363964314:1" } 
        ["_thumbnail_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "58" } 
        ["sample_text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "99 88 99 88" } 
        ["sample_image"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "58" } 
        ["sample_hjemmeside"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "www.ethic-clinique.no" } 
        ["sample_facebook"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "www.facebook.com/ethic-clinique" } 
        ["sample_telefon"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "99 88 99 88" } 
        ["sample_mailadresse"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "post@ethic-clinique.no" } 
        ["sample_senterbeliggenhet"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "Tredje butikken til høyre i andre etasje." } 
        ["sample_logo"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "Tredje butikken til høyre i andre etasje." } 
        ["sample_repeatable"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(74) "a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"image";s:2:"89";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"desc";s:0:"";}}" } 

}
```

Appreciate any help on this :)

Comment: Where did you define `$post_meta_data`? I suppose nowhere - the error message is exactly stating the problem...

Comment: You're right, I don't think I have defined '$post_meta_data' anywhere. Thinking it was taken care of in meta_box.php that came with the zip. Do you know how I can fix this? Or maybe explain the different parts of the script so I understand it better? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how that plugin works, and you have posted code that is probably missing context but you need to define `$post_meta_data` before running line:

```
$custom_image = $post_meta_data['image'][0];
```

It seems that the plugin is using post meta so you should need something like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'hjemmeside', true); ?>
```

But rewritten to save the data as a variable instead of `echo` it. Guessing based on the code you posted, I believe you need:

```
$post_meta_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'image', true);
if (!empty($post_meta_data[0])) {
  $custom_image =  wp_get_attachment_image($post_meta_data[0], 'thumbnail');
}
echo $custom_image; // if desired
```

Untested, but stands a good chance of working.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :) I'm really unsure how to define post_meta_data. I've been searching nonstop for several hours trying to find a way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work. So without knowing the results if I had defined (?) post_meta_data i tried your solutions: The rewritten code gave an illegal string offset and the echo didn't give me the image, but a "0". You know what that means?

Comment: Please post complete error messages. They should identify which line is problematic. I will edit my answer to include a debugging line, or two.

Comment: string(1) "0" 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/torvgaarden/single-butikker.php on line 29(or rather line 3)

Comment: `$prefix.'image'` or `$post->ID` is wrong. I assume the former, but it matches the pattern that you claim works for text fields. Try `var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID));` and edit the output _into your question_.

Comment: Did I understand you right if you told me to not use any of the scripts you suggested, but instead change it with `<?php var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID)); ?>`? In that case I got a pretty long line with text.. :)

Comment: Yes, it would spit out a lot of info but it tells me what I need. Look for `sample_image`. That key is set but there is not no image data. It actually is "0". The code I posted works (pretty close) but something else is wrong elsewhere. Your image data is not saved in the first place.

Comment: I actually hadn't noticed that, but when I press update the image disappears.. Maybe it's the plugin? It's weird because everything else get's saved, even the color picker and slider when i tried them out.. it's just the image

Comment: I think I fixed the image not saving, I put the new var_dump in the question post :)

Comment: So what are you saving? The attachment ID?

Comment: I'm not sure. [This](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/metaboxes/meta_box.php) is the script I'm using for the metaboxes. The bottom section supposedly saves the captured data. There's a function called `save_box( $post_id )`, is that what you mean? :)

Comment: See the edit for modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'hjemmeside', true);
```

Assumes hjemmeside is the name of your custom field key.